# How do I configure Spring security to work on Virgo - using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-annotations

I am having a problem configuring my web-app to use Spring security on Virgo Tomcat Server.
I am using annotation based configuration - and would like to maintain using Annotations if possible.

Below show the logs containing the error message.

```
[2012-06-26 16:19:30.661] ERROR start-signalling-1           o.a.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/virgo]   Exception starting filter securityFilter org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:217)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:145)
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:122)
at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:91)
at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:247)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:294)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:291)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:229)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:143)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My web.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Java-based Spring container definition -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components 
    that makeup this application -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>org.TSSG.social.statusnet.config</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Secures the application -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Enables support for DELETE and PUT request methods with web browser 
    clients -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The @Configuration class giving me trouble contains the following code

```
package org.TSSG.social.statusnet.config;
--imports removed ---
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:org/TSSG/social/statusnet/config/security.xml")
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Bean
public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
    return Encryptors.noOpText();
}
```

}

And finally, my security.xml contains the following.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security                    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- Authentication policy -->
    <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" />
    <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signin/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"  />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                           users-by-username-query="select username, password, true from Account where username = ?"
                           authorities-by-username-query="select username, 'ROLE_USER' from Account where username = ?"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Just to add a quick note, My application works perfect on Apache tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reviewing my build (using maven). I had the wrong directory structure therefore WEB-INF/lib was not getting picked up correctly for dependencies.

Problem has now been solved and working correctly!